# Django: where do I call settings.configure?

Tags: python, django, django-settings

The Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#custom-default-settings) say that I can call `settings.configure` instead of having a `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`. I would like my website's project to do this. In what file should I put the call to `settings.configure` so that my settings will get configured at the right time?

**Edit** in response to Daniel Roseman's comment:

The reason I want to do this is that `settings.configure` lets you pass in the settings variables as a kwargs dict, e.g. `{'INSTALLED_APPS': ..., 'TEMPLATE_DIRS': ..., ...}`. This would allow my app's users to specify their settings in a dict, then pass that dict to a function in my app that augments it with certain settings necessary to make my app work, e.g. adding entries to `INSTALLED_APPS`.

What I envision looks like this. Let's call my app "rexe_app". In wsgi.py, my app's users would do:

```
import rexe_app
my_settings = {'INSTALLED_APPS': ('a','b'), ...}
updated_settings = rexe_app.augment_settings(my_settings)
# now updated_settings is {'INSTALLED_APPS': ('a','b','c'), 'SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST': True, ...}
settings.configure(**updated_settings)
```

Comment: Why not to use  `from rexe_app.default_settings import *` and  `INSTALLED_APPS += ('a', 'b')` directly in user's project settings file if you want things done that way?

Comment: @alko: I started with that approach, but it doesn't work well with updates to my software. For example, if I want to add another app to `INSTALLED_APPS`, or modify another setting like `TEMPLATE_DIRS`, I need to tell all my users to change it in their settings file. My user base would prefer for it to be handled automatically and invisibly.

Comment: don't get it. you simply add new app to `INSTALLED_APPS` in `rexe_app.default_settings` and this is handled by `+=` operator, your users just do `pip install rexe_app upgrade`

Comment: @alko: are you saying `INSTALLED_APPS += ('a', 'b')` should go in the user's project settings file, or `rexe_app.default_settings`? I'm pretty sure neither way works. `rexe_app.default_settings` can't read in the user's `INSTALLED_APPS` to append to it.

Comment: @RexE, does this approach satisfy your needs, or you are still uncertain/looking for best solution, and if yes, why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its not quite equivalent, since settings `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` updates defaults, found in `django.conf.settings.global_settings`, while parameter for `configure` completely ignores them, so you have to add some additional processing.

Beware, first, that you can't modify `INSTALLED_APPS` on the fly, as they are examined once on settings processing. For example, to apply modifications to INSTALLED_APPS in Apache-deployed application, you need to restart Apache.

Second, as settings are imported, therefore this point is prone to injections of some sorts, and is highly vulnerable to expose them to users.

If this is a meta app, there are two possibilities:

1. If you want to provide default settings for `django`-wise setting, add following to `default_settings.py` in your app:

   ```
   INSTALLED_APPS = ('default_app', )
   ```

   Just make sure you don't import `default_settings.py` in your app, and make your users add to their settings.py

   ```
   from rexe_app.default_settings import *
   INSTALLED_APPS += ('users_app', )
   ```

   that effectively will set `INSTALLED_APPS` to `('default_app', 'users_app', )` for your end users.
2. In case you need `rexe_app`-wise settings, you can default them in your app's `__init__.py`:

   ```
   from django.conf import settings
   REXE_APP_CONFIG_PARAM = getattr(settings, 'REXE_APP_CONFIG_PARAM', 
       'default_param_value')
   ```

   so when user needs to change default `REXE_APP_CONFIG_PARAM` he needs to just add

   ```
   INSTALLED_APPS = ('rexe_app')
   REXE_APP_CONFIG_PARAM = 'user_param_value'
   ```

   to his `settings.py`.

Comment: Thanks for the info and caveats! Luckily, I got the `settings.configure` approach to work, so I'll try that for now.

Answer (score 3):

It would be in your wsgi script. please have look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/howto/deployment/modwsgi/).

You could run `mysite.settings.configure()` instead of `os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using wsgi then call that in your wsgi script before running the app.

If you want to do this for dev server, pass it as command line option (mentioned on the same page).

```
django-admin.py runserver --settings=mysite.settings
```

Comment: it doesn't work though, it can't find my project name even when I have it the exact same as in wsgi.py, something is missing