# Why is Django unable to run properly?

Tags: python, django

I am recently working on Django following the description from the book Python Crash Course. I followed every step and tried to restart from the beginning a couple of times, still unable to solve the problem(Even reinstalled MacOS to get a cleaner desktop). Here is my code:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    '''A topic the user is learning about'''
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        '''Return a string represent model'''
        return self.text
```

The tracebacks are below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bryan/Desktop/python/learning_log/learning_logs/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    class Topic(models.Model):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 108, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 253, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 135, in check_apps_ready
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
[Finished in 304ms with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['python3', '-u', '/Users/bryan/Desktop/python/learning_log/learning_logs/models.py']]
[dir: /Users/bryan/Desktop/python/learning_log/learning_logs]
[path: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

Edit:
The code is in the file models.py

Comment: When does this error occur? When you try to import `Topic`? When you try to apply migrations? Please provide a little more information

Comment: See where it says `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.`? Did you try doing those things? What happened when you tried doing those things?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26082128/improperlyconfigured-you-must-either-define-the-environment-variable-django-set this post in relation to actual error. This will likely have the answer.

Comment: try this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826534/how-can-i-correctly-set-django-settings-module-for-my-django-project-i-am-using

Comment: Hi @Mitchell van Zuylen, the error occurs when I try to run the code in SublimeText.

Comment: Hello @KarlKnechtel, thanks for the suggestion. I have not tried to do those things because honestly, I do know how to... Just started learning programming from almost the beginning.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the relating post, @Mitchell van Zuylen. I have checked out but I do not think I understand how to solve it. Specifically how to `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings`, may I know a little more information about that? Sorry, I am new to programming.

Comment: SublimeText is an editor. When you are running python, it uses a python kernel (In your case Python3. Usually this will be in a terminal. The terminal will also be where the error you posted will be located. The kernel needs to have access to the settings file. Can you add `settings.configure()` at the top of the script you are trying to run?

Comment: "I have not tried to do those things because honestly, I do know how to" So... look them up? You can literally put `django settings.configure` into a search engine; the first result I got was [this previous Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19855160/django-where-do-i-call-settings-configure). For setting environment variables, you have a "how do I use my computer?" question, not a programming question anyway.

Comment: "Specifically how to `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings`" Do you know what a command line is? What operating system are you using?

Comment: Hello @MitchellvanZuylen, thanks a lot for the reply! I think I have figured out where the problem is. I tried to run models.py file directly in SublimeText which made the error. It turns out that when working with Django we barely run .py files directly as Mr.Japhyr mentioned.

Comment: Hi @KarlKnechtel, sorry if I made any stupid questions. I have been using computers for many years. Just been recently learning to program and found out it is fascinating. But there is a lot I do not quite understand especially when problems occur. I will make a note of your words and try to do a search next time and post more programming-related questions. Anyway, the positive side is this problem has been sorted out with help from the community! I am sorry again if I made you any trouble and thanks for your suggestions! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the error is happening because you're running the models.py file directly. In working with Django, you rarely run a .py file directly. Usually you run some commands in the terminal, and then you interact with your project in a browser.

- Are you working in an active virtual environment?
- Have you run the `makemigrations` command for your app?
- Have you run `python manage.py migrate`?
- What happens when you run `python manage.py runserver`?

Comment: Thank you a lot @japhyr! The problem has been sorted out. As you mentioned, I did run models.py directly in SublimeText which made the error and I have figured out we should use terminals rather than run the files directly in the editor when working with Django. After I modified the models.py and admin.py files, I `makemigration` and `migrate` the manage.py in the terminal. When I checked localhost/8000 everything works great!

Answer (score 0):

There is small mistake you are trying to access the `text` in `__str__` method and due to which it failed in order to access the `text` you need to change the code like `self.text`

```
def __str__(self):
    '''Return a string represent model'''
    return self.text
```

Comment: You are right. How negligent I was. But the problem is still there after I changed text to self.text